# Debug.Assert UI dialog on phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there a way to show `Debug.Assert` dialogs on Windows Phone 8? When I run my code under debugger I can see the assert message(s) in the debug output. However, I need to explicitly look; I'd rather get a dialog in my face (similar to desktop) even when debugger is not attached.

Comment: Similar question (with no answer): [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/42830321-d7b9-42bc-805c-32220ed284e8)

Comment: In the worst case, you can just make your own Assert method.